# Google Ads attribution in Firebase SDK

Tags: android, firebase

We have recently switched from **Google Analytics SDK** to **Firebase SDK** in our Android app.

Before that, we used `INSTALL_REFERRER` to get the user's source and medium.
Now we have started an App Campaign on Google Ads and `INSTALL_REFERRER` no longer works, though conversions keep coming.

How do we use Firebase SDK to know that user came from Google Ads campaign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the [Play Install Referrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) API.

The link above cautions that the install referrer information will be available for 90 days and to only invoke the API during the first run of the app to avoid unnecessary API calls.

Here's an example (taking from the link above), assuming you have added the library to your `build.gradle` file:

*Initialization:*

```
private lateinit var referrerClient: InstallReferrerClient
...

referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

    override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
        when (responseCode) {
            InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                // Connection established
            }
            InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                // API not available on the current Play Store app
            }
            InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                // Connection could not be established
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
})
```

*Getting the referrer:*

```
val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
val referrer = response.installReferrer
val clickTimestamp = response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
val installTimestamp = response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
```

*Wrapping Up:*

```
referrerClient.endConnection()
```

*Checking for gclid (Google Ads)*

```
if ("gclid" in referrer) {
  //report to Firebase Analytics
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Google Ads App campaign, because the links are managed by Google Ads and are `intent://` links leading straight to the Play Store without any familiar attribution parameters.

Comment: @CamaroSS could you use something like this `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())` to get the intent?

Comment: doesn't work because Google doesn't deeplink into the app itself, just the installation page on market.

Comment: @CamaroSS, I think the [Play Install Referrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer) API is what you want. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot! You might want to update your answer that one would check the received referrer for `gclid` to know if the user came from Google Ads. I'll accept it then.

Comment: @CamaroSS, I've updated my answer with a brief `gclid` detection example. Not sure if you wanted to get the value for the `gclid` though.

Comment: No, that's perfect. The question was about detecting that user came from Google Ads.

Answer (score 0):

In this way, we will determine `gclid` only if the user has clicked on the advertisement in the browser, but if he clicked on the advertisement in the `play market`, then nothing will work.

Comment: It's unclear how this answer relates to the question.

Comment: since I could not write a comment - I wrote back :)